# How can I detect when changing a List size in Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the current size of the List 3 items in the Inspector :

[image: List in Inspector]

When changing the size for example to 4 it's duplicating the last item but I want it to add a new empty Conversation item :
There are two Locked Room items :

[image: Last item is duplicated instead creating a new conversation item]

This is how I declared the List :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditorInternal;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
```

What I tried so far :

Created a Editor script with a button :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if(GUILayout.Button("Add new item"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But now I'm having two problems :

1. The button is override the other two buttons I already had Load and Save and I want this button the "Add new item" to be position always before the Canvas and after the last item.
2. How do I increment the List inside the button event in the editor script ?

[image: after changes]

The script as it is now :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversationtrigger = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0.2f,0.3f,0,0), "Add new item"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.conversations.Add(new Conversation());
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the button to GUI.Button instead GUILayout.Button to set the position of the button.

But the button now is gone vanished and also the other two buttons from my first top screenshot the Load an Save also gone vanished.

This is the script for the load and save buttons :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class SaveConversationsButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        ConversationTrigger dialoguetrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            dialoguetrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(dialoguetrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            dialoguetrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could probably achieve this by using a button in the Custom Inspector. Instead of manually setting the number, have the button increment and add a new empty object using a function.

Comment: Otherwise, you may have to create a script to loop through and check for duplicates on an update call. Not really sure how to override the default behavior itself.

Comment: @TimHunter I updated my question edited with what I tried. Added a button but now the button is override the other two buttons and also the new button is not position in the right place. I think the button should be always be before the Canvas and after the last conversation item. And inside the button event in the script how do I increment the list ?

Comment: You should be able to reference the list since it's public I assume. Use GetComponent to reference the script holding the list, then it should automatically increment when you use a `list.add(new Conversation)` command.

Comment: As for the overriding your other buttons, I would need to see how your inspector script is set up. Not sure why they would disappear unless you delete your previous buttons on accident.

Comment: As for repositioning the button, you can set the element ordering using the method described [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1567638/how-can-i-change-the-variables-order-in-inspector.html). I think you can reference the button element by using the label like when you create it, but I am unsure of this and cannot test it currently.

Comment: The script of the button is the only one that I'm using for the inspector. The ConversationTriggerEditor in my edited part of my question.

Comment: Ah jeez, missed that. Sorry! Yeah, if that's all you have in your editor then the "Add new item" button is all that you've declared. What happened to your other button declarations?

Comment: @TimHunter I edited my question once again at the bottom I added the script as it now. Tried to set the button position but now the button is vanished like deleted and also the two other buttons load and save also not exist.

Comment: @TimHunter You right I forgot to add it. Added the script to my question on the bottom the inspector editor script of the load and save buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but I think you want to combine those if they're both trying to be an editor for the same object type. One might override the other. As for your "add item" button disappearing, I figure that's because it's being passed the wrong kind of parameters. I'm not seeing anything in [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Button.html) that accepts a Rectangle as a parameter.

Comment: I will combine. As for the button I'm using GUI.Button not GUILayout.Button here is the documentation for the GUI.Button that accept Rect : GUILayout.Button https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html

Comment: Ah, did not catch that! Thanks for showing me that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `MonoBehaviour.OnValidate()` method

Edited from [this blog post](http://cjf.in.ua/812-unity-editor-extensions-the-power-of-onvalidate/):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OnValidateExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations;
    private int previousConversationsCount;
    private int currentConversationsCount;
 
    void OnValidate()
    {
        currentConversationsCount = conversations.Count();

        if (previousConversationsCount != currentConversationsCount)
            Debug.Log($"Conversations count has changed: {previousConversationsCount} => {currentConversationsCount}");

        previousConversationsCount = currentConversationsCount;
    }
}
```